# web api can't fetch complex parameter from client, have to use a dynamic type

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I have a aspnet core web api and an angular client. When I want to call a method in web api I send a object from client, and api receive it as a method parameter. But in this case the client always logs error "*HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: 'OK ...}*" in console.
The obj class sent from client is:

```
export class TaskProgress{
    id:string="";
    taskId:string="";
    discription:string="";
    workingHours:number=0;
    status:string=""; 
}
```

The call in client:

```
  createTaskProgress(dto:TaskProgress):Observable<TaskProgress>{
    return this.http.post<TaskProgress>(`${environment.apiUrl}/TaskProgress/Create`,dto);
  }
```

The ViewModel as parameter in api:

```
public class TaskProgressDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long TaskId { get; set; }
    public string Discription { get; set; }
    public double WorkingHours { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }//committed staged unstaged
}
```

The method in api controller:

```
    [HttpPost("Create")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Add(TaskProgressDto dto)
    {

    }
```

I found a solution which works that substitude class TaskProgressDto to a dynamic type like below:

```
[HttpPost("Create")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(dynamic dto)
{

}
```

But I don't know why, can I just use the explicitly class TaskProgressDto?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are same differences between the object that you send from de client, and the object that you expect on your server.

```
export class TaskProgress{
    id:string="";
    taskId:string="";
    discription:string="";
    workingHours:number=0;
    status:string=""; 
}

public class TaskProgressDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long TaskId { get; set; }
    public string Discription { get; set; }
    public double WorkingHours { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }//committed staged unstaged
}
```

You have to **respect**, the **same params name**, and also the **same params type**.
So, try this on your client, and change the object.

```
  export class TaskProgress {
        Id: number = 1;
        TaskId:number = 2;
        Discription:string = "";
        WorkingHours: number=0;
        Status: string=""; 
    }
```